# When does a derived class need to implement a method as const?

Tags: c++, oop, constants

Why doesn't `CC::onError` need be const in the below example? `BB:onError` has to be const else compiler error.

BB is required to implement onError as const else compiler error.

CC can be implemented as non-const. Why?

```
class AA  {
public:
    AA() {};
    virtual ~AA() {};

    // On any error
    virtual void onError(int32_t error) const = 0;
};

class BB : public AA {
public:
    BB() {};
    virtual ~BB() {};

    virtual void onError(int32_t error) const {
        //changing x is invalid here due to const
        //method required to be const else compiler error
    }
protected:
    int x;
};

class CC : public BB {
public:
    CC() {};
    virtual ~CC() {};

    virtual void onError(int32_t error)  {
        x = 5;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CC c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't CC::onError need be const in the below example?

Because a member function isn't required to be `const`.

The problem is that you expect it overrides `A::onError` and that's why C++11 introduced `override` keyword.
It's a subtle error, but the fact is that you are not overriding `A::onError`. You are declaring a new virtual member function in `C` that actually hides `A::onError`.
Try to use this:

```
class CC : public BB {
public:
    CC() {};
    virtual ~CC() {};

    virtual void onError(int32_t error) override  {
        x = 5;
    }
};
```

The compiler will tell you explicitly what's the error:

> error: 'virtual void CC::onError(int32_t)' marked 'override', but does not override

On the other side, the following code would be correct (at least it overrides `A:onError` as expected) but for the fact that it doesn't compile for you can't modify `x` being `onError` `const`:

```
virtual void onError(int32_t error) const override  {
    x = 5;
}
```

Unless, of course, you define `x` as `mutable`:

```
mutable int x;
```

I wouldn't recommend it, for `mutable` is meant for slightly different cases, but [it works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NiDn1ATw1u4suBrZ).

Comment: @Thediz You are welcome. Do not forget to accept this or another question to help future readers to find quickly the information they are looking for. SO is a valuable tool as long as all the participants make it so. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`AA::onError() const` is pure virtual i.e. you must provide definition for it in descendant class (BB). Note, that const is a part of method signature.

CC has `onError() const` defined in an ancestor (BB) and when you define `BB::onError()`, it doesn't override `BB::onError() const` as its signature is different. You just define a new method.

Answer (score 0):

A non-const method in a derived class can't override a const method in a base class, even if all parameter types are the same. The function `C::onError` hides the function `B::onError` instead of overriding it.

In the case of `B::onError`, it is legal for it to have different cv-qualification than `A::onError`, but since `A::onError` is pure, there has to be *some* non-pure overrider in order to get to a concrete class. If `B::onError` and `C::onError` are *both* non-const, then `C` is an abstract class. The issue is ultimately with `C`, not `B`, since `C` is what you are trying to instantiate.